# Magento 2 how to add Materialize javascript in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I have tried to add materialize js to Magento 2 but it does not work. I have my materialize js in `theme/web/js`.

then I have the `requirejs-config.js` in `theme/`

this is the code:

```
var config = {

    // When load 'requirejs' always load the following files also
    deps: [
      "js/materialize"
    ]

  };
```

and I put my `materialize.js` inside this code:

```
   define([
      "jquery"
    ], 
    function($) {
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code in `requirejs-config.js` of respective theme.

```
var config = {
    paths:{
        materialize : 'js/materialize'
    },
    shim: {
        materialize: ['jquery'],
    }
};
```

and add below code in your `.phtml` file to check is it correct:

```
<ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>

<script>
require(["jquery","materialize"], function($){
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.collapsible').collapsible();
    });
});
</script>
```

add below fonts and css in your `default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" src_type="url" />
        <css src="css/materialize.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

***You will see like below :***

[image]

Comment: I tried it and is not working, the carousel and parallax are not doing the right animations, what could it be? do I need to put the whole materialize.js functions inside define()?